# Pasting link from clipboard to next window as a URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to copy and paste clipboard link to newly opened browser tab. The fresh tab is opening but nothing is happening. Clip method in result have this url link but I got error.
What I have till now :

```
def switch_tab(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[len(self.driver.window_handles) - 1])
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.get(clip)
```

and clip method

```
def clip():
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()

    while not r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD"):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    result = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    print(result)
    return result

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
          raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
      TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Have you not tried assigning the clipboard to a variable then using that variable as the url? Or have I completely misread what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have it in variable called result